# C# for ASP.NET: Errors from added code

Tags: c#, asp.net, debugging

I'm supposed to take some code from my professor and add it to the code I have, but I'm experiencing issues with the function I was told to include and I'm not really sure how I can resolve this issue. I've read some of the other questions that were posted already, but I can't really be sure those are the same thing.

> ERROR RESOLVED: Were brackets missing and mistyped variables & method flying around (provided by answer below!)
>
> Error 1: Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
>
> Error 2: Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
>
> Error 3:  Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected
>
> Error 4: clsDataLayer' does not contain a definition for 'SavePersonnel'
>
> Error 5: clsDataLayer' does not contain a definition for 'GetPersonnel'

This was supposed to be an add in and move on kind of deal--not sure if it's my code that's the issue or the code supplied. How do I fix this?

**Code Provided: Error 1, 2, & 3**

```
// ERROR OCCURS at bool
public static bool SavePersonnel(string Database, string FirstName, string LastName,
string PayRate, string StartDate, string EndDate)
{
bool recordSaved;
try {
// ERROR 2 OCCURS HERE after new     !!!!!
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
"Data Source=" + Database);
conn.Open();
OleDbCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
string strSQL;
// Add your comments here
strSQL = "Insert into tblPersonnel " +
"(FirstName, LastName, PayRate, StartDate, EndDate) values ('" +
FirstName + "', '" + LastName + "', " + PayRate + ", '" + StartDate + 
"', '" + EndDate + "')";
// Add your comments here
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
command.CommandText = strSQL;
// Add your comments here
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
// Add your comments here
conn.Close();
recordSaved = true;
} //<-- ERROR 3 is at this curly bracket
catch (Exception ex) {
recordSaved = false;
}
return recordSaved;     
}
```

**Code Provided: Error 4**

```
// ERROR AFTER clsDataLayer.
    if (clsDataLayer.SavePersonnel(Server.MapPath("PayrollSystem_DB.accdb"), 
    Session["txtFirstName"].ToString(), 
    Session ["txtLastName"].ToString(),
    Session ["txtPayRate"].ToString(),
    Session ["txtStartDate"].ToString(),
    Session ["txtEndDate"].ToString())) 
    {
    txtVerifiedInfo.Text = txtVerifiedInfo.Text + 
    "\nThe information was successfully saved!";
    }
    else
    {
    txtVerifiedInfo.Text = txtVerifiedInfo.Text +
    "\nThe information was NOT saved."; 
    }
```

**Code Provided: Error 5**

```
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
//Declare the Dataset
            dsPersonnel myDataSet = new dsPersonnel();
//ERROR AFTER clsDataLayer.
            myDataSet = clsDataLayer.GetPersonnel(Server.MapPath("PayrollSystem_DB.accdb"));
//Set the DataGrid to the DataSource based on the table
            grdViewPersonnel.DataSource = myDataSet.Tables["tblPersonnel"];
//Bind the DataGrid
            grdViewPersonnel.DataBind();
```

**Additional Code adding, required for Error 5:**

```
// This function retrieves all data from tblPersonnel table
public static dsPersonnel GetPersonnel (string Database, string strSearch)
{
    dsPersonnel DS;
    OleDbConnection SqlConn;
    OleDbAdapter sqlDA;
    
//Opens OleDbConnection
    sqlConn = new OleDBConnection("PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
            "Data Source=" + Database);
    
//Employee Search (procured from video, add in later?
    if (strSearch == null || strSearch == "")
    {
    sqlDA = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from tblPersonnel", sqlConn);
    }
    else
    {
    sqlDA = new OleDbAdapter("Select '' from tblPersonnel where LastName = '" + strSearch + "'", sqlConn);
    }

//Sets Value of DS
    DS = new dsPersonnel();

//Fills Table with Data
    sqlDA_Fill(DS.tblPersonnel);

//Return value
    return DS;
}//End Function: Public static dsPersonnel GetPersonnel
```

Comment: sounds like a missing }

Comment: @LoekD Yes, you were right. I failed to move the end of my public class for the file to the end, though this brought up quite a few errors. Will respond soon if I can't understand it.

Comment: @LoekD Thanks for your help, it was very beneficial to me. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Error 1, 2 & 3

> Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct

In C#, methods should always be part of a class.
In your case, you have your method flying around without a parent, so the compiler will complain with this error.

To fix this, define your method inside a class:

```
// C# class
public class clsDataLayer
{
    // This functions insert data into tblPersonnel table
    public static bool SavePersonnel(string Database, string FirstName, string LastName, string PayRate, string StartDate, string EndDate)
    {
        bool recordSaved;
        try
        {
           OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + "Data Source=" + Database);
           conn.Open();
           OleDbCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
           string strSQL;

           // Add your comments here
           strSQL = "Insert into tblPersonnel " +
           "(FirstName, LastName, PayRate, StartDate, EndDate) values ('" + FirstName + "', '" + LastName + "', " + PayRate + ", '" + StartDate +  "', '" + EndDate + "')";

           // Add your comments here
           command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
           command.CommandText = strSQL;

           // Add your comments here
           command.ExecuteNonQuery();

           // Add your comments here
           conn.Close();
           recordSaved = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            recordSaved = false;
        }
        return recordSaved;     
    }

    // This function retrieves all data from tblPersonnel table
    public static dsPersonnel GetPersonnel (string Database, string strSearch)
    {
        dsPersonnel DS;
        OleDbConnection SqlConn;
        OleDbAdapter sqlDA;

        //Opens OleDbConnection
        sqlConn = new OleDBConnection("PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + "Data Source=" + Database);

        //Employee Search (procured from video, add in later?
        if (strSearch == null || strSearch == "")
        {
            sqlDA = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from tblPersonnel", sqlConn);
        }
        else
        {
             sqlDA = new OleDbAdapter("Select '' from tblPersonnel where LastName = '" + strSearch + "'", sqlConn);
        }

        //Sets Value of DS
        DS = new dsPersonnel();

        //Fills Table with Data
        sqlDA_Fill(DS.tblPersonnel);

        //Return value
         return DS;
     }
     //End Function: Public static dsPersonnel GetPersonnel
}
```

## Error 4 & 5

> clsDataLayer' does not contain a definition for 'SavePersonnel'

This is clearly related to the previous error.
Since `SavePersonnel` was wrongly declared, the compiler complains it does not exist.

Once we solve errors 1, 2 & 3, the errors 4 & 5 should disappear too.

Comment: Thank you very much, was very helpful. All is working now--with the exception of code I forgot I would need to add in from additional lines I added. :) I appreciate your assistance.